# iPhone 4 cannot connect to internet after iOS6 update

Tags: iphone

Ever since I updated my iPhone 4 to iOS6, I'm not able to connect to the internet except when I have a WiFi signal to connect to. Any suggestions about the cause or solution?

Comment: Could you give us more details? Did nothing else change after you upgraded, but the cellular data broke? Have you rebooted the phone?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things to check on (in the order you should try them):

- Check your settings on "Cellular Data" as they might disappear with the iOS6 update (that's what happened to me anyway)
- Try turning on and off your flightmodus
- Reset your Network settings
- Try rebooting your iPhone
- (Restore your iPhone)

Although the latter isn't the ideal solution, it might solve your issue. But only try this in worst case scenario (since it's pretty radically).

Anyhow, if neither of above options solved your issue, [you're not alone](http://mashable.com/2012/09/28/ios-6-wi-fi/). I recommend you pay a visit to your Apple Store.